# Android - Error when inflate Menu Item into Actionbar

Tags: android, android-studio, android-actionbar, android-menu, android-inflate

I have the following problem, I need to inflate just one item (logout) to the `ActionBar` displayed in the `LoginActivity`. But it throws an `"unexpected EOF!"`. So I have tried different ways of inflating the item to showing it up in the action bar but still without good results, at the end I've put the error message.

This is an image of example (what is showing)
[no item showed..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OrGFx.png)

My code is the following:

app/java/package/MainActivity.

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    CircleImageView profile_image;
    TextView username;

    FirebaseUser firebaseUser;
    DatabaseReference reference;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar();

        profile_image = findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
        username = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.userId);

        firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(firebaseUser.getUid());

        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                User2 user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User2.class);
                System.out.println(user);
                Log.d("Userz",user.getUsername());
                username.setText(user.getUsername().toString());
                if(user.getImageURL().equals("default")){
                    profile_image.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
                } else {
                    Glide.with(MainActivity.this).load(user.getImageURL()).into(profile_image);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
        //getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu,menu);
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        Log.d("Itemid",item.toString());
        switch(item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.logoutItem:
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, StartActivity.class));
                finish();
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

app/res/menu/menu.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/logoutItem"
        android:title="Logout"
        app:showAsAction="always"

        />
</menu>
```

app/res/layout/activity_main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/MenuStyle">


            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:id="@+id/profile_image"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/userId"
                android:text="username"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Error Message:

```
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:631)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:518)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.findViewById(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:403)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.findViewById(AppCompatActivity.java:191)
        at com.affinity.affinityteam.firebase_chat_try2.MainActivity.onCreateView(MainActivity.java:40)
        at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:6184)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:389)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:780)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:631)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:518)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.findViewById(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:403)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.findViewById(AppCompatActivity.java:191)
        at com.affinity.affinityteam.firebase_chat_try2.MainActivity.onCreateView(MainActivity.java:40)
        at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:6184)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:389)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:780)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:631)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:518)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.findViewById(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:403)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.findViewById(AppCompatActivity.java:191)
        at com.affinity.affinityteam.firebase_chat_try2.MainActivity.onCreateView(MainActivity.java:40)
        at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:6184)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:389)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:780)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:631)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:518)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.findViewById(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:403)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.findViewById(AppCompatActivity.java:191)
        at com.affinity.affinityteam.firebase_chat_try2.MainActivity.onCreateView(MainActivity.java:40)
        at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:6184)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:389)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:780)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)

    read: unexpected EOF!
```

Comment: try to add setHasOptionsMenu(true); in onCreate.

Comment: But i'm not using fragments... doesn't work with activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the error **unexpected EOF** has nothing to do with your code but with some configurations about the buffer sizes that may be of a fixed size. To solve that you can set the buffer sizes to **off** under Developer options settings.

If not enabled yet, you can enable the settings under **About** and click **Build number** until the see a toast confirming that developer options are enabled.

**EDIT**:
And inside your toolbar XML node, add the id attribute with value `toolbar` as called in `onCreate` callback

```java
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

//not sure that toolbar is not null since in xml there is no id toolbar
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar();
```

Since the view with `toolbar` as id could not be found, findViewById returns null and setSupportActionBar will get a null value that means no Toolbar to cast as ActionBar.

Modify your toolbar XML and add the id attribute as stated below:

```xml
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/MenuStyle">
```

Good luck

Comment: Even with simulator i have to do that??

Comment: yes! using an emulator or a physical device you proceed the same way. Try it and let us know

Comment: but do you still see the error? the unexpected EOF?

Comment: Thanks but i've already found the solution, Hemal Patel founded that i was missing the definition of the id in the toolbar (activity_main.xml)

Comment: Okay great, but next time you encounter a unexpected EOF inside a logcat don't think about the code. think about the logcat itself first.

Answer (score 0):

In your `onCreate()` method you are trying to initialize toolbar with below code:

`Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
 setSupportActionBar(toolbar);`

Where you have not specified the `id` attribute for the toolbar view in your XML file.

**Please specify the id for the toolbar in XML and then try to run it.**

I think you will resolve this issue by following the above solution.